# Поддержка MIME type application/stream+json в Angular2

Tags: java, spring, http, angular2

С выходом новой версии Spring 5 появился модуль WebFlux(реактивный подход).
В [документации в пункте 23.2.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) есть поддержка MIME `application/stream+json`. В этом типе подразумеваются множество json-объектов через разделители.

Может ли angular2 правильно обрабатывать такой MIME-type?

Т.е. обрабатывать отдельные json объекты, которые были получены, до полного завершения запроса.

**UPD**

Похоже можно, [Тут предлагают делать обертку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825110/5308586) над `Connection` и подписывать на событие `onProgress`.

Остается вопрос, есть ли в самом angular2 такая возможность? Так как он очень быстро меняется и многие issues, связанные с данной проблемой, либо закрыты либо удалены.

Comment: Вы всегда можете в запросе указать например `this._http.get(uri, { responseType: 'text' })` и интерпретировать его как душе угодно.

Comment: Ключевой момент, который интересует, есть ли потоковая обработка данных до завершения запроса или все данные обрабатываются после завершения запроса.  Ваш комментарий не отвечает на этот вопрос.

Comment: Не уверен, но похоже нельзя. Вот тут народ предлагает решение через стороннюю библиотеку, возможно вам подойдет. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115764/consuming-a-restapi-stream-with-angular2

Comment: Похоже можно, [Тут предлагают делать обертку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825110/5308586) над `Connection` и подписываться на событие `onProgress`

Comment: Смахивает на ту же самую библиотеку, только самописную. Но главное чтоб работало. :)